# Dynamic form and model creation based on user's input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-view-controller, mongoid

I'm hoping someone can help guide me on the best way to do this. I am setting up a sign-up form for people to list their skills/credentials in various jobs

Schema is along these lines using Mongoid and Inheritance

```
class Person 
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String 
  field :education, :type => String 
end

class Accountant < Person
  field :cpa, :type => Boolean
  field :active_cpa, :type => Boolean  
end

class SoftwareDeveloper < Person
  field :full_stack, :type => Boolean
  field :language, :type => Array  
end
```

So users will come to a sign up page mysite.com/persons/new where there will be a form to select various jobs (listed and grouped by the various industries: finance, engineering, marketing) and based on the user's selection, a more detailed view will show up specific to that job function. (e.g. software devs can list programming languages and accountants can list if they have a CPA).

My question is, what's the best way to handle this in the controller and view layer? There's about 100 different job functions I'm covering so i'd like to combine the controller and view instead of redirecting the users to mysite.com/accountants/new or mysite.com/engineers/new and have a controller / view for each specific job.

Can someone please help guide me on the best way to approach this? I know I will have to use jQuery and maybe some ajax calls to render the detailed forms, but what do I do with the controller because form_for is tied to users at first and the model there has limited attributes so I'm not sure how to get the params and pass them into the params hash with validations for more specific jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem like this recently. I ended up setting up my form using form_for on the base type, Person in your case. Within the form, I created a fieldset for the base fields and separate fieldset tags to represent the extra fields available in each subclass like so:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>

<fieldset id="base">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.check_box :name %>
  <!-- ... -->
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="accountant">
  <%= fields_for :accountant do |f| %>
     <%= f.label :cpa %>
     <%= f.check_box :cpa %>
     <!-- ... -->
  <% end %>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="software_developer">
  <%= fields_for :software_developer do |f| %>
     <%= f.label :full_stack %>
     <%= f.check_box :full_stack %>
     <!-- ... -->
  <% end %>
</fieldset>
```

This use of fields_for will result in the form POST providing your "create" method in the controller with params like:

```
params[:person] = { :name => "Joe Smith", ... }
params[:accountant] = { :cpa => true, ... }
params[:software_developer] = { :full_stack => false, ... }
```

In your form, you'll also want to have some way of specifying the type of job. In my case, I used a simple select tag:

```
<%= select_tag :job_type, options_for_select(@job_types) %>
```

This will provide you with params[:job_type] in your controller. From there, the "create" method needs to figure out which job type the user selected and then create the correct subclass and use the supplied parameters. I used a case statement for this:

```
case params[:job_type]
when :accountant
  @person = Accountant.new(params[:person].merge(params[:accountant]))
when :software_developer
  @person = SoftwareDeveloper.new(params[:person].merge(params[:software_developer]))
when ...
end
```

If you've got lots of subclasses, that might not be very scalable. So what you could do is arrange that params[:job_type] gives you the name of the class to create as the value the form submits. Then you could do something like:

```
@person = params[:job_type].constantize.new(params[:person].merge(params[params[:job_type].underscore])
```

This code uses the job type field to convert to the class name and then again to find the correct fields for the subclass.

Finally, you'll want to use a bit of jQuery to hide and show the different field sets when the user selects a different job type. To do that, attach a .change() handler to the select_tag element and have it hide all the fieldsets, then show the one fieldset with an "id" that matches the selected job type. Let me know if you need example code for this.

As a finishing touch, you might think about rendering your job-specific field sets in partials so that your main form just has a series of calls to render all the different types of jobs.

I don't know if there are better ways to do this, but this approach worked really great for me and allowed me to have a single controller and set of views to manage the creation and editing of a whole parent/child subclass tree.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's been super helpful. I'm spending this weekend trying to implement this in my code. Could you possibly give me an example of the .change() method you mentioned? I'm not sure if I should just have a form loading all the different fieldsets for each job_type or just have a base and append the specific fields based on the job_type selected. In any case, thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: Yeah, I can update the answer with an example change method. One thing you could do in the .change method is dynamically load the fieldset for the selected job type from the server. Some people advocate doing AJAX using JSON, and that's ok sometimes. But in cases like this, you want your form snippets ready formatted loaded from the server. That way you have all your layout done on the server-side in ERB or whatever and you don't need to mess about in javascript creating form fields from JSON etc.

Comment: You might want to check whether `params[:job_type]` is an authorized value before passing it to `.constantize.new` to avoid arbitrary code execution.